# java.lang.RuntimeException: ImageReaderContext is not initialized

Tags: java, android

```
mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 4);
mVirtualDisplay = mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(TAG, mWidth, mHeight, mDPI,DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, mImageReader.getSurface(), getimg(), null);
image = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage();
```

> 12-14 13:57:06.893: W/System.err(15177): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   ImageReaderContext is not initialized 12-14 13:57:06.927:
>   W/System.err(15177):  at
>   android.media.ImageReader.nativeImageSetup(Native Method) 12-14
>   13:57:06.961: W/System.err(15177):    at
>   android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextSurfaceImage(ImageReader.java:298)
>   12-14 13:57:06.992: W/System.err(15177):  at
>   android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextImage(ImageReader.java:344) 12-14
>   13:57:07.024: W/System.err(15177):    at
>   com.zed1.luaservice.ScreenService.acquireLatestImage(ScreenService.java:109)
>   12-14 13:57:07.056: W/System.err(15177):  at
>   com.top.colour.ColorUtil.snap(ColorUtil.java:89) 12-14 13:57:07.087:
>   W/System.err(15177):  at
>   com.top.colour.FindImageFuzzy.execute(FindImageFuzzy.java:55) 12-14
>   13:57:07.111: W/System.err(15177):    at
>   org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaState._call(Native Method) 12-14
>   13:57:07.138: W/System.err(15177):    at
>   org.keplerproject.luajava.LuaState.call(LuaState.java:602) 12-14
>   13:57:07.165: W/System.err(15177):    at
>   com.zed1.server.LuaService.call(LuaService.java:33) 12-14
>   13:57:07.193: W/System.err(15177):    at
>   com.zed1.server.LuaThread.callLua(LuaThread.java:71) 12-14
>   13:57:07.220: W/System.err(15177):    at
>   com.zed1.server.LuaThread.run(LuaThread.java:49)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, however not on my device but on one of my customers. I found someting on [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/camera/camera-core/src/main/java/androidx/camera/core/AndroidImageReaderProxy.java?source=post_page---------------------------%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F) site. They use the following code:

```
Image image;
    try {
        image = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        /* In API level 23 or below,  it will throw "java.lang.RuntimeException:
           ImageReaderContext is not initialized" when ImageReader is closed. To make the
           behavior consistent as newer API levels,  we make it return null Image instead.*/
        if (isImageReaderContextNotInitializedException(e)) {
            image = null;
        } else {
            throw e;  // only catch RuntimeException:ImageReaderContext is not initialized
        }
    }
    if (image == null) {
        return null;
    }



private boolean isImageReaderContextNotInitializedException(RuntimeException e) {
    return "ImageReaderContext is not initialized".equals(e.getMessage());
}
```

I don't know yet, if it solves the issue, because the crash does not occur on my device. Let me know if it helps.